When is it acceptable to commit directly to main/master?
Working with Git, I’ve often heard that committing directly to the main (or master) branch is generally discouraged. Instead, many teams adopt workflows where all changes are made in separate branches, reviewed via pull requests, and then merged into main. In fact in my last job, it was company policy to ALWAYS branch, with no exceptions.
But is this always necessary? Are there situations where committing directly to main is acceptable, or even preferable? And if there are,how can the risks best be mitigated?

Committing directly to main is discouraged because it bypasses code reviews, risks broken builds, and potentially reduces traceability. However, I can think of certain  small, low-risk changes (eg., typo fixes), solo development, experimental branches, or urgent hotfixes, that might warrant a direct commit to main. But the problem then becomes: "where to you draw the line", and that's not so easy to answer. Thus for me it makes sense to adopt the approach of your previous employer - never push to main.

when you are one man  army then maybe

@sahasrara62 why "maybe"? I do PR in my solos as well but always considered myself too inert to stop for a second and reconsider. Is there really a benefit when solo?

@nicholaswmin Yes, there's a benefit when solo.  Several.  You can keep commits for a single feature in one branch and then squash to preserve a clean commit history.  You can stop work on a feature and have a clean copy of your production code if you need to make an emergency release, without the hassle of branching off a prior hash.  Pretty much all the reasons not to do it in a multi person project still exist.  It's just the only person you inconvenience is yourself.

@nicholaswmin u r general of your project, do whatever you want :D

@RobertLong If committing to main bypasses code reviews in your shop, you should perhaps reconsider whatever it is you put in place that stops code reviews in that situation. There are plenty of shops where that code can easily be reviewed before being pushed, and more than a few where code is reviewed automatically as it is written, before anybody even thinks about committing.

Obviously nothing is always necessary. But for most people, having a hard and fast rule to follow provides a good deal of psychological comfort, as well as giving you the excuse, should anything go wrong, that you were just following the rule, and thus helping to avoid blame for any problems that might occur.

Change to read me, other doc, template or a config file that will effect only one feature and is urgent

A central component of Trunk Based Development is reducing the number of long-lived branches. For some teams, this means committing directly to the trunk or main branch. Only with larger teams would Trunk Based Development use feature branches, and even then, the intention would be for those feature branches to only live for a couple of days before being committed to trunk.
It should be noted that Trunk Based Development isn't for all teams. It does have a high bar for starting - high levels of robust automated test coverage at all levels, fast tests, a stable pipeline, and feature flags, to name a few. It also requires discipline to pair or mob program or set aside time to do good post-commit peer reviews to make sure that knowledge is spread across the team.

I would also include "when you are the lone wolf" in this answer. If you are the only person working on the project, then you are the only one to suffer when something goes wrong. Personal projects (which are just a variant of "the lone wolf project") are another example where you can just commit and push to main. But in a team environment, trunk-based development is the only way to do this without causing chaos on a daily basis.

I have been a “lone wolf” rarely and being the only one who suffers is little consolation. I’d rather spend a bit of extra time and be on the safe side. Plus working on several items at the same time (some feature, a bug fix, a more urgent bug fix) means I act in several roles.

@GregBurghardt I don't believe that lone wolf or personal projects mean that you shouldn't have at least some of the safeguards that make it safe to commit to main possible. There's no reason to not have fast automated tests, good test coverage, and a pipeline. The only thing that you will probably skip is peer review, since you may not have peers to review the work with regularly.

even TBD uses branches

@Ewan TBD only uses branches in three cases: (1) short-lived feature branches for large teams, (2) changes that are disruptive and destabilizing that cannot be addressed with feature flags, and (3) releases to ensure that a release can be supported until it is end-of-life. Only 1 and 2 result in commits to the branch, and 1 is only for large teams and 2 tends to be working around past architectural decisions

I always did a review before a commit. Needs some focus because there is nobody telling you if the review is careless.

@thomasOwens you could summarise that as "TBD always uses branches"

@Ewan Except...it doesn't. It almost never uses branches.

In almost all workflows, committing directly to main should be avoided. It introduces unnecessary risk, creates bad habits, and undermines good software engineering practices. Even in solo projects, adhering to a branch-and-merge workflow instills discipline and consistency.
Key Risks of Direct Commits

No Peer Review: Skipping pull requests bypasses valuable code reviews, increasing the chance of bugs or poorly considered changes.
Broken Builds: Without isolated testing or CI/CD checks in a branch, direct commits can destabilise the project.
Reduced Traceability: Branch-based workflows link changes to specific issues or features, providing a clear history. Direct commits make debugging and auditing harder.
Conflicts in Collaboration: For teams, direct commits can cause merge conflicts, overwrite others' work, or introduce uncoordinated changes.
Bad Habits: Solo developers committing directly to main may develop habits that are incompatible with team workflows, leading to difficulties in collaboration.

Why a Blanket Rule Works Best
Exceptions, such as "small, low-risk changes" or "time-critical fixes," introduce ambiguity. They require subjective judgement, create debates, and may be misused. Implementing safeguards for exceptions (eg., defining rules or monitoring adherence) often requires more effort than simply using a branch-and-merge process.
By enforcing a strict "no commits to main" rule:

The workflow remains consistent and predictable.
Risks of errors and conflicts are minimised.
Developers maintain good habits, whether working solo or in teams.

An Exception: Trunk-Based Development
As discussed in the answer by Thomas Owens, Trunk-Based Development (TBD) is an exception where committing directly to main is not only allowed but central to the workflow. TBD works by minimising or eliminating long-lived branches and relying on practices such as:

Robust automated test coverage.
Fast and reliable CI/CD pipelines.
Feature flags to manage incomplete or experimental code.
Disciplined collaboration through post-commit peer reviews, pairing, or mob programming.

However, TBD requires a high level of engineering maturity and may not suit teams without these prerequisites. For most teams, the risks outweigh the benefits, and adopting a branch-and-merge workflow is the safer choice.
Best Practices for Enforcing the Rule

Enable Branch Protection: Configure Git to prevent direct commits to main or require pull requests for all changes.
Use CI/CD Pipelines: Ensure branches are tested before merging, reducing the risk of introducing errors.
Document Policies: Make the rules clear to all team members, emphasising the importance of branching workflows.
Monitor Compliance: Use pre-commit hooks or review tools to enforce adherence to the policy.

Summing Up
Committing directly to main is a practice that should generally be avoided. For most teams, adopting a strict branch-and-pull-request workflow ensures stability, collaboration, and accountability. The minor inconvenience of creating branches is far outweighed by the benefits of better code quality and consistent habits. While Trunk-Based Development offers an alternative approach, it demands a level of process maturity that is out of reach for many teams.

Your risks aren't risks of committing to main, but poor practices. No peer review? If you have good merging and tagging hygiene, using tooling to diff and review changes at any point becomes trivial. Broken builds? A robust CI/CD pipeline should be non-negotiable, so reverting a commit on a failed build shouldn't be a problem. Traceability? It can still be maintained through commit messages. Conflicts? Rejected by git or by failing tests. The risks seem to expose other poor practices on the team, so it's a case where trunk-based development would be used without the prerequisites in place.

To be clear, I do agree with your last sentence. A lot of teams don't have the maturity in place to commit directly to main without blowing the world up around them. But that doesn't mean that committing to main or trunk-based development isn't a better way of developing software. It's rather that a lack of investment in good practices and technical excellence means teams have to adopt more wasteful practices.

Thanks for your comment.  I agree that the risks I outlined are more reflective of poor practices than inherent flaws in committing to main. As you rightly point out, Trunk-Based Development, when paired with robust CI/CD, feature flags, and disciplined team practices, can be highly effective. However, as we seem to agree, many teams lack the maturity or technical skills to implement this successfully, leading to the adoption of branch-based workflows as a safeguard. For these teams, the "waste" of branching is a pragmatic trade-off for stability and collaboration. (+1) to your answer BTW :)

Commit directly to main/master" is not the same as "push directly to main/master." Points 1, 2, and 3 are not relevant in most organizations because you must push your branch, and you can guard this with pull request policies and CI/CD tools. Point #4 is an issue no matter what your branching strategy is. If I make a change on the same line as you do, we have a merge conflict no matter which branch it exists in once we merge our work together. (1/2)

(2/2) The premise of your answer makes me think you are addressing committing and pushing directly to main without proper guards in place. I though the OP implied that people are still doing PRs - then again the OP didn't specify.

@GregBurghardt good points. Perhaps we should seek clarification from the OP.

commiting direct to main === pushing to main in my book

It doesn’t reduce traceability (point 3). Linking to issues or whatever can be done in the commit messages just the same.  Unless you rely on some pre-generated “Merged pull request #654” for this traceability.

@GregBurghardt where do you see the difference between "committing to main" and "pushing to main"? Do you want to distinguish between your local copy and the one in a "central" repository for this? (What is done in your local copy doesn't really affect others, so you can do what you want there. Though pushing to a different remote name than you have locally can be a bit of a hassle, so I tend to avoid this.)

"Do you want to distinguish between your local copy and the one in a "central" repository for this?" @PaŭloEbermann, that is exactly what I had in mind. Committing is one thing. Pushing is another. You can still commit to main and push to your private repo. Then you can send a pull request to pull your main into someone else's main. Some teams isolate work with forks rather than branches.

There's at least one situation where pushing commits straight to the main branch is highly desirable: If the merge of a branch/PR goes wrong and leads to a broken build, it's a real pain to have to create a PR and have someone review and merge it all the while CI is screaming at you and nobody can work. It's much better to fix the mis-merged chunk in a one-line direct commit so that a working state is restored in a matter of minutes, not an hour or more. (Having CI always pre-test all possible merges of all open PRs with current main tip is often prohibitively expensive.)

A similar situation is when you need to revert a problematic change. It makes little sense to have a clean revert reviewed since it's just the inverse of a previously reviewed change, and there's often quite some urgency involved when it comes to reverting broken stuff.

In my experience, adhering to strict rules does not instill discipline but quite the opposite. What a good software developer really needs is to have the discipline to understand and think about what she is doing to the greatest degree possible, and most rules of this nature are about avoiding thought. ¶ If you have an undisciplined team, giving them more crutches to avoid learning discipline will leave you with an undisciplined team forever. If, instead, you gave them options and ask them to think about and justify their decisions, you are helping them down the path to being better.

If you are the only person working on a project and the project isn't in any way "live" yet, but maybe you are still experimenting with approaches, it is fine to work on main.

This was my first thought as well. If you're the only author and/or if the project is very small and/or the changes are very small - why not?

@Vilx- so you can revert more easily. Work on a branch, if it is a dead end, throw away the branch and try again with a fresh branch

Actually, when I work on something entirely new, I would never "throw away a branch" because things don't come to my mind linearly, and whatever comes to my mind is immediately fixed or altered. Until, of course, you reach something stable and useful.

@jwenting - Sure. I mean, branches have a lot of good properties, that's why people use them. I'm just saying that there are circumstances where it's OK to not use them - if you want to. For example, I'm currently going through Advent of Code puzzles and checking them in my repo as I solve them. And I've got absolutely no need for branches.

Basically Never.
Even with trunk based development you are either using feature branches and PRs or are just using main as a dev branch in all but name.
Sure you can mitigate the risks by auto reverting commits if checks fail, but jeeze, now you have feature branching where you feature branch is local main.
Now obvs if you are a lone dev or its a tiny change to a rarely changed repo, who's gona care. But that doesn't make it good practice.

It seems to be generally discouraged indeed.
First of all we can note that “don’t commit to master” is an overly
specific-sounding shorthand which really means: don’t commit and push to the
main branch all by your lonesome.  At least get someone else’s input first (code
review).  Maybe also other things like so-called CI checks.  It just happens
that the process of code review is implemented with feature branches on pull
requests which target the main branch.  That’s where that don’t-do comes from.
Things can change once one of the variables in the previous paragraph are taken
away.  Like the implication that you are working on a team.

My team does commit to master/main directly for one specific circumstance: pinned version numbers for third-party packages in requirements.txt files.
In the develop branch we are liberal about accepting new versions of third-party packages by default, so that if a problem arises we learn about it quickly.
So in the develop branch, our requirements.txt file might look like this:
packagea
packageb
packagec

But in the main/master branch we want to be very conservative and not accept new versions of third-party packages by default, so we use pinned versions:
packagea==2.4
packageb==1.07
packagec==6.1

We achieve this by committing this version of requirements.txt directly to main/master.


Committing directly to the main (or master) branch is generally discouraged.
Instead, many teams adopt workflows where all changes are made in separate branches, reviewed via pull requests, and then merged into main

You're confusing similar mechanisms with unrelated principles
These have nothing to do with each other:

Treatment of proposed code (your code before review etc.)
Treatment of accepted code (already-checked-in code)

Case #1: Proposed code
The underlying principle here is that code that is unaccepted must not be in the codebase!
This is no different from how items that are unaccepted shouldn't be in your carry-on baggage on an airplane... you don't carry things you haven't accepted responsibility for. It's just common sense.
"But where else can I put my code?", you ask?
Well it depends on your tooling:

On plain git, your only realistic available options are to mail around diffs (patches), or to work on a temporary branch that you then share.

On GitHub, you can also just fork the repository, and work on the copied branch on your forked repo, and then ask for a pull request.

With other source control systems (SVN, hg, GitLab, etc.)... consult the user manuals to figure out your options.


Notice that using branches here has nothing to do with whether you even have a code review/testing/validation/etc. process. It has to do with acceptance of responsibility. There are other mechanisms that facilitate a separation of proposed code from accepted code; you just pick whatever is easiest for you/your team.
The implication here is that the only times you directly commit to the branch of interest (whether master or another long-lived branch) is when you lack any acceptance mechanism (teammates doing reviews, CI/testing, etc.) and you yourself wrote the entire code, thus accepting responsibility implicitly.
i.e. basically never, except for untested solo projects.
Case #2: Accepted code ("long-lived branches")
If your proposal is to merge your candidate code into master, then you are not really "using branches" for your project.
What is relevant here is what comes after code acceptance.
And what you do here depends entirely on the nature of your project and tooling.
It is generally something you decide based on a lot of factors, including:

How sharp or stable your project's ABI boundaries are

How expensive your test suite (and CI/CD process in general) is

How good your tooling is

How easy it will be for you to merge your code later vs. now

Whether your different branches have different acceptance criteria

What your teammates find easier


etc.
It's a subjective choice with lots of factors, but typically, I think this pattern is something you'll see a lot:

When your final artifacts are typically "monolithic"/self-contained (e.g., statically linked binaries), you might find trunk-based development easier.

When your final artifacts are typically puzzle pieces that are then fit together (e.g., shared libraries), then you might find long-lived branches to be easier to deal with.


Your team's mileage may vary.

No, branches are not always necessary. You will run into development teams that want to avoid thinking as much as possible, and so introduce hard-and-fast rules such as "never commit directly to master, no matter how much it slows our development," or "always follow these formatting rules, even when it makes the code harder to read," but that's just the nature of the industry.
The only way you're going to get a real understanding of how to answer the, "should I commit this directly to main" question is to analyse it yourself, many times in many specific situations, working out the advantages and disadvantages for that specific situation. General answers may provide ideas to use in your analysis of any specific situation, but this is one of those questions where there are so many environmental factors involved that there's absolutely no way of giving rules, and even guidelines tend to be problematic.
In general, you want to think about the benefits you get from making the branch versus the cost of making the branch, and what risks (if any) the branch is mitigating.
For example, can you test your changes locally? Or are you one of those unlucky people who can do adequate tests only by pushing a branch to another server? If the latter, are those tests helping you or hindering you, and by how much?
As one extreme example, if you're fixing a spelling error in a documentation file that is not checked in any way by the automated test system, and you have to wait a half hour for that pointless act to complete if you push a branch, and you can't merge without those tests completing, you're now starting to pay some serious costs to use a branch fix the spelling error rather than just pushing a change directly up to the main branch.
Another of the many things to think about is what kind of review you need, and how will it be done. Say you have a small, pretty obvious change that you have very high confidence is fully tested locally, but you feel you want someone else to give it a quick sanity check. Can you just call someone over to your computer (or do a screen share), show them the code, and show them that the related tests pass? Or do you (for whatever reasons) have to use much less efficient methods of communication where it's more easily shared by taking the time to put the commit on a branch and push the branch?
As I mentioned at the start, each individual situation is complex and requires a thoughtful approach if you really want to get the best balance of cost versus risk for your particular situation. (And even thinking about cost versus risk as a bunch of work in and of itself.) This actually isn't all that much work to do if you practice it regularly and get used to it; in some situations it soon becomes instinctual. But being this mindful and disciplined about your software development process is not something most people are used to, so you can probably see why many developers prefer to just pick a good looking rule, make everybody follow it, and avoid all that hard thinking about what they're doing.
